# Update Azure container with changes to Git repository

Tags: git, azure, github, azure-blob-storage

I'm currently using Azure's static website utility for blob containers to host my site. Is there a clean way to link the container to the corresponding Github repo, and update with changes?

Previously, I was using Azure VM for this task, and would ssh in and `git pull` before I start the server. Can I accomplish the same for the $web container created on Azure?

I have looked at docs for deploying to Azure through Github Actions, but these seem to create a new container instead of updating an existing one.

Comment: Azure devops pipeline?

Answer (score 0):

You can use GitHub Actions workflow to automatically deploy your static website to Azure from GitHub when you make changes to your site's code

You can create a service principal with contributor role to your Azure Resource Group in which the static website is deployed

You can configure the JSON format of the service principal details as the GitHub Secret in your repository

```
{
    "clientId": "<GUID>",
    "clientSecret": "<GUID>",
    "subscriptionId": "<GUID>",
    "tenantId": "<GUID>",
    (...)
}
```

Now, you can set up the workflow in your GitHub actions for the below actions:

1. Login to Azure with the service principal credentials
2. Azure CLI action to upload your code to blob storage container
3. Log out of your Azure Account

Using GitHub Actions to deploy to your static website, you do not need to create new container. Instead, you can use the existing container

Reference: [Use GitHub Actions to deploy a static site to Azure Storage | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blobs-static-site-github-actions)